# Android GPS location using Google Play Service and Wifi / Data network

Tags: java, android, gps, google-play-services

We are actually developping an application in which we need to determine our "current" mobile location.

Reading the documentation, it seems that the Google Play services is a better way to handle this problem, instead of using the old LocationManager.

**Problem**

Even if we specified the different access rights in the manifest, it's not possible for us to get the location via WIFI or Network Data. In fact the last known location is always null.

In the other hand, if we activate the GPS, the last location is the good one.

**Code**

*Manifest contains :*

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NFC" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
    <!--
     The following two permissions are not required to use
     Google Maps Android API v2, but are recommended.
    -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

*The service :*

```
public class GoogleLocationService implements
        GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    private Activity mActivity;
    private Location mLastLocation;
    private boolean mResolvingError;

    public GoogleLocationService(Activity mActivity) {
        this.mActivity = mActivity;
        this.mResolvingError = false;
    }

    public synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(mActivity)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
        mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(
                mGoogleApiClient);
        Log.e("mLastLocation", mLastLocation + "");
        if (mLastLocation != null) {
            Log.e("lat/lng", mLastLocation.getLatitude() + " " + mLastLocation.getLongitude() + "");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        if (mResolvingError) {
            // Already attempting to resolve an error.
            return;
        } else if (connectionResult.hasResolution()) {
            try {
                mResolvingError = true;
                connectionResult.startResolutionForResult(mActivity, 1001);
            } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                // There was an error with the resolution intent. Try again.
                mGoogleApiClient.connect();
            }
        } else {
            // Show dialog using GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog()
            Log.e("GoogleLocationService", connectionResult.getErrorCode() + "");
            mResolvingError = true;
        }
    }

    public boolean ismResolvingError() {
        return mResolvingError;
    }

    public void setmResolvingError(boolean mResolvingError) {
        this.mResolvingError = mResolvingError;
    }

    public GoogleApiClient getmGoogleApiClient() {
        return mGoogleApiClient;
    }

    public void setmGoogleApiClient(GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient) {
        this.mGoogleApiClient = mGoogleApiClient;
    }

    public Location getmLastLocation() {
        return mLastLocation;
    }

    public void setmLastLocation(Location mLastLocation) {
        this.mLastLocation = mLastLocation;
    }
}
```

*The activity :*

```
 @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        if (!mServiceGoogle.ismResolvingError()) {  // more about this later
            mServiceGoogle.getmGoogleApiClient().connect();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        mServiceGoogle.getmGoogleApiClient().disconnect();
        super.onStop();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_position);


        mServiceGoogle = new GoogleLocationService(this);
        mServiceGoogle.buildGoogleApiClient();

    }
```

Are we missing something in this code to manage the current position in every way ?

Thanks for advance

Comment: check Settings -> Location -> on/off

Comment: *Are we missing something .. ?* yes, the part of the documentation of the `FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation` where is mention that **it CAN returns null** ... asked bazzilion times

Comment: It can rarely* return null in fact. And it doesn't return null with GPS activated. It returns null only (and every time) with Wifi or Mobile Data

Comment: Do you have internet ?